# How to show checkbox in the top left corner of its multiline text C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, checkbox, mfc

Is there a way to do this? Also, the lower text is truncated when I set it as multiline. Is there a way to increase the size of rect for the checkbox so that the multiline string fits in it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Top is possible.

Left is doubtful. you can try it.

In the below link look for "Text Alignment Styles"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf9hd91s.aspx

For setting the style use,

```
CButton::SetButtonStyle(UINT nStyle,BOOL bRedraw = TRUE)
```

Look for documentation here in below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1wax6c.aspx#cbutton__setbuttonstyle

**for multiline fit** probably you have to set the style to button using "setButtonStyle" with an option "BS_MULTILINE".

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CheckBox` together with a `Static`. My experience tells me that this workaround is good for many reasons. (E.g. you can easily make the checkbox look transparent, which would otherwise be excruciatingly hard.)